# Why does linearly independent spanning set imply minimal spanning set for a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Suppose $\beta$ is a linearly independent spanning set of some vector space $V$. Why must it be the minimal spanning set?

In other words, why can there not be two linearly independent spanning sets of a vector space $V$ with different sizes?

Comment: There are usually many minimal spanning sets. "Minimal" means you cannot remove any element without losing the spanning property. "Minimal" is different from "smallest"; _smallest_ things are unique, _minimal_ things usually not.

Comment: OK, I was a bit confused on that point, thanks. But what about my second question? Why can there not be two linearly independent spanning sets of a vector space V with different sizes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ and $w_1,\ldots,w_m$ are bases for $V$ where $n<m$.

By writing the $w_i$ in terms of the $v_j$, you create a system $w_i=\sum_j \alpha_{ij}v_j $.

In terms of coordinates, this means that the vector $w_i$ has coordinates $[\alpha_{i1},\alpha_{i2},\ldots,\alpha_{in}]$ in the basis of $v_i$'s. In other words, you have $m$ length $n$ vectors that you believe are linearly independent (since the $w_i$ are linearly independent.) You can put these in a matrix, and keep in mind you believe the rows to be linearly independent.

By using elementary row operations, though, you can put this matrix into row-echelon form, where it must have all zeros in the last row. This says that the last row is a linear combination of the rows above it, and that means that the $w_i$ weren't linearly independent after all. This contradiction shows why the assumption in the first line can never occur.

Comment: Sorry, can you clarify why in row-echelon form, it must have all zeroes in the last row?

Comment: @user156724 Row echelon form makes everything below the diagonal $a_{ii}$ entries zero. If the matrix is taller than it is wide, then an entire row lies underneath the diagonal.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $S$ is a proper subset of $\beta$ such that $\text{span}(S)=\text{span}(\beta)$. Choose $v\in \beta$ such that $v \not \in S$. So, there exist $a_i\in F$, $v_i\in \beta$, $1\leq i\leq n$ such that $\displaystyle v=\sum_{i=1}^n a_iv_i$ i.e.  $$0=\sum_{i=1}^n a_iv_i+(-1)v$$ which implies that $\beta$ is linearly dependent, a contradiction!So, $\beta$ is a minimal spanning set.

Answer (score -1):

Just a quick explanation from dimension theorem of vector space.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension_theorem_for_vector_spaces

Suppose you have $v_1$ and $v_2$; they are linearly independent and span $V$. Then they form the basis for $V$. As such the dimension of $V$ is $2$ and according to the dimension theorem, all set of linearly independent vectors that span $V$must be of size $2$ as well.

Comment: This is not very useful since the question is essentially "why is the dimension theorem true?" We can't invoke the dimension theorem to answer the reader's question.

Comment: Sorry I'm student as well. I thought refering to the standard theorem might be useful.

Comment: In many cases it is useful, but in this case it is [circular reasoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_reasoning).  The dimension theorem can't be used to justify itself ;)